# Adding options to SELECT tag via JS ..Are not styled by CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html-select

I have a select tag that looks like this:

```
<select style="background:#fa7171; color:#FFFFFF;" name="product_type_sub" id="product_type_sub" onChange="ajaxFunction(1);">
    <option value="None Selected">None Selected</option>
</select>
```

You can see the inline css sayin the font should be white, and it is at first. but I add/remove more options with Javascript and Ajax.

Here is how I add options:

```
next.options[i+1]=new Option(newFields[i], newFields[i], false, false);
```

But any options that I add are not in a white font, they ignore the CSS, is there a way to enforce this?

Thanks!!

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: Does it work if you set background color on option element directly?

Comment: I know that support for background -related rules on option elements is not that wide. For example, some browsers, ignore background-color completely (IIRC, Chrome and Safari). I'm not sure if it's the same with "color" rules.

Comment: @crescentfresh, I am seeing this happen in Chrome only, sorry for not specifying before.

Comment: @Kangax, based on the script I am showing how I add an option, how would I had styling to the option? Thanks.

Comment: You would set color on its style property - `var optionEl = new Option(newFields[i], newFields[i], false, false); optionEl.style.color = 'red'; next.options[i+1] = optionEl;`

Comment: @kangax thank you, you should put that as an answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: Here we go... Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set color on an option element directly. For example:

```
var optionEl = new Option(newFields[i], newFields[i], false, false); 
optionEl.style.color = 'red'; 
next.options[i+1] = optionEl;
```